# Bash/WSL - How to run command as root?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
>ubuntu1804.exe -c "echo $USER"
mpen
```

That runs the command as me, how do I run it as root?

The help page doesn't even mention `-c`

```
>ubuntu1804.exe help
Launches or configures a Linux distribution.

Usage:
    <no args>
        Launches the user's default shell in the user's home directory.

    install [--root]
        Install the distribuiton and do not launch the shell when complete.
          --root
              Do not create a user account and leave the default user set to root.

    run <command line>
        Run the provided command line in the current working directory. If no
        command line is provided, the default shell is launched.

    config [setting [value]]
        Configure settings for this distribution.
        Settings:
          --default-user <username>
              Sets the default user to <username>. This must be an existing user.

    help
        Print usage information.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out there's another command simply called `wsl` that lets you run arbitrary commands as arbitrary users:

```
>wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-18.04 -- echo "I am g$USER"
I am groot
```

N.B. you need to use separate args (instead of a string) for this one.

`-d` is optional. You can change the default distro like

```
wslconfig.exe /l
wslconfig.exe /s Ubuntu-18.04
wslconfig.exe /l
```

`wslconfig /l` appears to be equivalent to `wsl --list`

Comment: You win the internet for your echo example, as far as I'm concerned. Maybe it's an old joke by now, but I voted up your solution for that alone.

Answer (score 1):

Often the root account is not active by default

Do this (it will prompt you to select the password for root):

```
sudo passwd root
```

and then you can login as root:

```
su root
```

After you have done with activities that request root privileges, re-login back as user:

```
su <username>
```

Comment: You should use `su - root`, or, in general, `su - <username>` to log in with full user environment. To logout, you should use `logout` or simply `Ctrl + D` (in almost every terminal). Using `su` again will start a new session over the pre-existing root and the original user sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run multiple commands, just login as root:

```
wsl -u root
```

and run all commands interactively

Comment: If you're able to run commands interactively, you can just use `sudo` or `su` as normal. If you need to run multiple commands from Windows non-interactively, you can do `wsl -u root -- sh -c 'echo foo && echo bar'`

Comment: @mpen I had to run commands interactively to add my user to the sudo group :-)